# etoc: How to remove the title of local table of contents and add top/bottom horizontal rules?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I would like to use package `etoc` for getting local toc at the start of each chapter.
However, I struggle to:

1. hide the title "**Contents**"
2. add horizontal rules above and under this local toc entries
3. typeset the chapter content (mini toc with text) immediately after the chapter heading not on the chapter third page (the second is blank)

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\localtableofcontents 

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\etocsettocstyle` command provides means to set some stuff before and after the ToC, i.e. the horizontal rules. Using it in a very primitive way, it will also prevent the page break etc.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoc}


\newlength\tocrulewidth
\setlength{\tocrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begingroup
\parindent=0em
\etocsettocstyle{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}}
\localtableofcontents 
\endgroup


\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I could never figure it out in that clean way.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: You're welcome -- yes, the `etoc` manual is quite overwhelming and sometimes a little bit tricky to find the relevant information

Comment: I am sorry, but is it possible to left align the section entries for a bit more aesthetic look?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: I'll see what I can do

Comment: The reason for the indent is that here `etoc` is in compatibilty mode and delegates to the `scrbook` class the typesetting. I found no option in the KOMA-script manual, but adding `\def\scr@tso@section@indent{0pt}` (within `\makeatletter/\makeatother`) before `\localtableofcontents` does the trick. If however subsections are present, then you probably want to reduce their indent too. A more complicated ``\edef\scr@tso@subsection@indent{\the\dimexpr\scr@tso@subsection@indent-\scr@tso@section@indent}`` (before the fix for sections) does the trick then.

Comment: @jfbu: Perhaps you should provide an extra answer.

Comment: ok will do after a bit more researching the koma code

Comment: @jfbu: Well, KOMA, yes ... have a lot of fun ;-)

Answer (score 4):

(moved from a comment)

This is only an addendum to Christian's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312978/4686). The indent is explained from the fact that here `etoc` is in compatibilty mode and delegates to the scrbook class the typesetting. Hence sections in local TOCs appear as they would in the main TOC.

The `etoc` manual has an example of use `\KOMAoptions{toc=left}` but this does not work here as it needs some KOMA code which the `\etocsettocstyle{..}{..}` command has overwritten. I looked at `scrbook` code and found out that doing

```
\makeatletter
  \def\scr@tso@section@indent{0pt}
\makeatother
\localtableofcontents
```

solves the indent problem. However, a subsection would still be indented as in the main TOC. For lack of better solution I can propose:

```
\makeatletter
  \edef\scr@tso@subsection@indent
    {\the\dimexpr\scr@tso@subsection@indent-\scr@tso@section@indent}
  \def\scr@tso@section@indent{0pt}
\makeatother
\localtableofcontents
```

There may be an interface in KOMA to these indents but I did not (immediately) figure out how.

Full code (from Christian's answer):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoc}


\newlength\tocrulewidth
\setlength{\tocrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begingroup
\parindent=0em
\etocsettocstyle{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}}
\makeatletter
  \edef\scr@tso@subsection@indent
    {\the\dimexpr\scr@tso@subsection@indent-\scr@tso@section@indent}
  \def\scr@tso@section@indent{0pt}
\makeatother
\localtableofcontents 
\endgroup


\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) ..................... (filler)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer coincidentally I added to the just uploaded  (not yet on mirrors) slightly extended etoc manual some new sample code which in particular shows how to add these rules above and below in a non-separable by pagebreak way. (this is another topic)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the updated etoc manual in fact contains a conversion into etoc lingua of the book class code; thus all internals are revealed and can be customized at will, and in particular be adapted suitably for local tables of contents.

Comment: That is very nice and helpful indeed. Any progresses to support local .lof etc. or is this the next project with `elof` and `elot` and `elistofanything` packages? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree that `etoc` should apply to list of figures and list of tables. It does not because when I started doing `etoc` I had never seen any personal utility in including list of figures or list of tables in my manuscripts ... and I basically did not care and hardly knew about them. Nevertheless, supporting `\listoffigures`,  `\listoftables`  is now on `etoc`'s agenda indeed... but this can't be soon. (perhaps TL2017, never underestimate the pressure induced on package authors via this mechanism of yearly releases!)

Comment: I think, local `\listoffigures` etc. are useful for authors that combine several articles/documents to some kind of `proceedings` or a `thesis` and want to maintain the per-sub-document structure rather than merging all lists together.